# f2py: limit.h file missing in numpy in Windows

Tags: numpy, f2py, g77

I’m having trouble compiling some FortranIV code using f2py and the g77 compiler. I need to do this to call some very old code written in Fortran to an already existing Python module. I have gcc installed through MinGW but I’m not sure if that makes any difference. I am also running Python 2.7 with Numpy 1.7 and SciPy 0.12. My OS is Windows7 x64 but I have made sure that all my installs are 32bit versions. I am new to Python, Fortran and this forum so please bear with me.
The error I am getting when I compile the code with f2py is as follows:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_common.h:291: limits.h: No       such file or directory
error: Command "gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O2 -w -Wstrict-prototypes -    DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -    Ic:\users\ncd69~1.boh\appdata\local\temp\tmpxbl4sc\src.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-    packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -    c:\users\ncd69~1.boh\appdata\local\temp\tmpxbl4sc\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.c -o     c:\users\ncd69~1.boh\appdata\local\temp\tmpxbl4sc\Release\users\ncd69~1.boh\appdata\local\temp\tmpxbl4sc\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.o" failed with exit status 1
```

In order to isolate the problem I have used a test code that is compatible with the gfortran compiler. I make a call to the required compilers using ‘-c –compiler. The test is on the same lines as your basic ‘Hello World’. The error thrown up is identical for the real and test code. I looked up the erroneous file ‘npy_common.h’ and found that line 291 calls to include a  header: limits.h.
Since the error occurs in the Numpy libraries  I am assuming that the error is with Numpy? I can’t seem to figure out why this error would occur.

Comment: The problem is with your gfortran/gcc, not with numpy.

Comment: I have rebuilt Python and Numpy using the instructions given in the following link: http://scientificcomputingco.blogspot.com/2013/02/f2py-on-64bit-windows-python27.html
on a virtual machine to test the process. Unfortunately now I get the error _ValueError: Symbol table not found_ when trying to access _"C:...\numpy\distutils\mingw32compiler.py"_